# Просторечное "ить"

Tags: просторечия

***Ить*** — просторечное ***ведь***. Употребляется ли оно по-прежнему?

Встретил в книжке дефисное написание: *нам-ить.* Это ошибка?

Comment: Хоть я и принял ответ, но про дефисное написание хотел бы ещё услышать мнения, хорошо, если развёрнутые (можно в виде комментариев). Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А почему бы ему не употребляться? "Ить" я точно слышал, и многократно. Вполне в ходу, но тут надо учитывать, что это не самостоятельное слово, а просто вариант произношения. Точно так же, как "чё" вместо "что".

*В деревнях что только не употребляется, да и в городе немало можно услышать. Своими ушами слышал "спинжак" (это пиджак, если кто не догадался). Квартирная хозяйка у меня в далёкие времена говорила про сына "он у меня такой нервенный". Подруга год работала учителем в деревне и привезла оттуда чудное слово "липиздричество". Никаких словарей не хватит.*

Насчёт дефисного написания - так оно и пишется обычно, но это не правило, а просто авторская передача простонародной речи.

Comment: Интересный и полезный ответ, спасибо! Ну что, может, помиримся?

Comment: @Артём Луговой, не вижу предмета для ссоры. И прошу прощения, если обидел, заносит меня временами. Борюсь, но не всегда выходит.

Comment: Ну вот и славненько, freim! =) Вы меня тоже простите, если я был неправ.

Answer (score 2):

[**Ить**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/172367/%D0%98%D1%82%D1%8C) (в словаре Т. Ф. Ефремовой):
*част. разг.-сниж.*
Употребляется при подчеркивании чего-либо сказанного или при противопоставлении сказанного чему-либо другому; ведь.

Нашлись примеры употребления.

*— Это ж чуть ли не сотня верст, княже! — ахнул Травень. — А нам ить еще и струг на волоке тащить* (В. Елманов. Поднимите мне веки).

*Нам ить уже нужно будет сворачиваться и направляться в Астрань, чтобы на корабль грузиться* (К. Калбазов. Вепрь. Феникс).

*— Ну, шевелись, родимая! Шустрей греби домой! Нам ить засветло добраться надо. Тут уж не до устали* ([Э. Нетесова. Подкидыш](http://loveread.ec/read_book.php?id=11499&p=1)).

Мне кажется, что дефисное написание ошибочно (см. примеры).
В словаре говорится, что "ить" — это частица, поэтому считаю, что ее необходимо писать со словами раздельно (в списке "дефисных" частиц ее нет).
[Дефисное написание частиц](https://pravopisanie_i_stilistika.academic.ru/65/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%86)

Comment: Спасибо большое! Вот и мне казалось, что раз "ведь" без дефиса, то и тут не должно быть его.